# Is there something like localStorage on Android?

Tags: android

Is there something like localStorage on Android?

I would like store a data temporary. I know - I can use SQLite, but maybe there is something better?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you specifically are looking for one of those

- **[Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)**: Save files directly on the device's internal storage
- **[Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)**: A general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for all the possible storage types.

Answer (score 0):

yes sharedPreferences is for saving key value data.so you can save your json data in sharedPreferences. it is  easiest way to save data .just search how to use sharedPreferences

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

In android you can store data locally in many ways.
1. SharedPrefrence (for small data)
2. Sqllite (For Large data)
3. Realm (Very popular No-Sql database)
4. Phone memory
and many more ways to store data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExpiryDB](https://github.com/rdnasim/expirydb) for save data in local storage. It help to set data with expiry time.

Just simply use this library as

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.rdnasim:ExpiryDB:1.0.2'
}
```

Using

```
// for save
val key = "my_object"
val value = MyObject()
val expiryTimeMillis = 60000L // Expiry time in milliseconds

dbBook.write(key, value, expiryTimeMillis)

// for get
val retrievedValue = dbBook.read(key)
```